# If $A$ is compact and $B$ closed then $d(A,B)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

i want to prove that in a metric space if $A$ is compact , $B$ is closed such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $d(A,B)>0$.

i want to prove this by contradiction if i suppose that $d(A,B)=0$ how to find a contradiction ?

i apply the caracterisation of $\inf$ i found that $$\forall n>0, \exists (a_n)\subset A, (b_n)\subset B, d(a_n,b_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$$ As $A$ is compact there exists a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ but what to do to $(b_n)$ ? please

Comment: Use compactness : the minimum distance is realized by a point $a\in A$.

Comment: i use compactness to deduce a convergent subsequence to a point $a\in A$  what to to do with B ? @R.Alexandre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $d(A,B)=0$ then $\exists \{a_n\} \subset A$ and $\{b_n\} \subset B$ such that $|a_n - b_n | \to 0$. Now, A is compact so $\exists \{a_{n_k}\} \subset \{a_n\}$ such that $a_{n_k} \to a$. Now, $|a-b_{n_k}| \leq |a-a_{n_k}| + |a_{n_k}-b_{n_k}| \to_{k \to \infty} 0$.

Thus, we have show that $a$ is actually a limit point on $\{b_n\}$ and hence $a \in B$ but $a \in A$ and thus we have contradicted the fact that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.